# Direct users to two different URLs based on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple webpage for my upcoming wedding. We are having 2 events and thus there are two sets of info for when and where to be. I'm wondering if there is a way to prompt the user for an input, and based on their response have them redirected to the page with the correct info. So when they click "guest information" it will say something like "Enter Password" and if they enter password one they are redirected to site.com/page1 and if they enter password two they are taken to site.com/page2

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm not too great with server side scripts but I'm decent with front end (javascript and jquery). Please help! Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the easiest solution is to just set up two pages? Or make the user select one or the other explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ideally in web development, we would not expose a password on the client (front) end.  However, for a website that is private in nature anyways, this is likely fine.  Note that this is NOT using jQuery, but it could use it.

Here's the code to do what you request (but I didn't test it):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="passwordForNextPage" type="password">
      <button onclick="checkDestination();">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function checkDestination() {
          if (document.getElementById("passwordForNextPage") == "password1") {
            window.location.href = "/nextpage1.html";
          } else if (document.getElementById("passwordForNextPage") == "password2") {
            window.location.href = "/nextpage2.html";
          } else {
            alert("Please retype the password!");
          }
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: checked your code in this fiddle and got an error http://jsfiddle.net/DwWF4/

Comment: Should work now...just a couple typos:  http://jsfiddle.net/DwWF4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make a form with an input field, on submit check the value of the field, and assign to `window.location.href` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to be very secure, just a "View Source" will reveal the password, but it's probably fine for your needs and you can use the following:

**HTML:**

```
Enter Password: <input type="password" id="pwd">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var password = $('#pwd').val();
    if (password == 'pass1') {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    } else if (password == 'pass2') {
        window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.location.href property. To open it in new window, you need to use
window.open() method.

eg. window.open('http://www.facebook.com');   // This will open the specified link in new window